# Принципы русской орфографии 1

Tags: орфография

К какому принципу орфографии можно отнести слово *скрипка*? Не могу понять. К фонетическому относятся слова, предполагающие различное написание одной и той же морфемы в соответствии с различиями в ее произношении. Под этот принцип не подходит вроде. Морфологический тоже. Традиционный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово *скрипка* иллюстрирует морфологический принцип русской орфографии. Исторически оно связано с глаголом ***скрип***еть и сохраняет написание корня.